# Is a Mongo ObjectId string representation guaranteed to be hexadecimal?

Tags: mongodb, format, objectid

According to [Mongo documentation on `ObjectId()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/object-id/), the string representation seems to be hexadecimal right now, and trying to initialize an `ObjectId()` with a non-hexadecimal string of wrong length leads to failure.

Is this guaranteed to be this way?
Can I rely on an `ObjectId()` to be a hexadecimal string for the foreseeable future?

Answer (score 2):

I have been using MongoDB for the past 4 years. I dont think that they will be changing this basic functionality in any of the future releases. If they do that, lots of code will not be backward compatible and will break huge number of softwares.